# Characterisation of absolutely continuous measure on the real line

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\lambda, \nu$ be two Radon measures on $\Bbb R$ such that $\lambda(\Bbb R)< \infty$. Show that the following are equivalent:

1. $\lambda \ll \nu$;
2. $\forall \epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda((a_i,b_i))< \epsilon$ if $(a_1,b_1),\dots, (a_m,b_m)$ is a disjoint family of open intervals such that $\sum_{i=1}^m \nu((a_i,b_i))< \delta$.

It could be useful to recall that the following characterisation holds: $$\lambda\ll\nu \iff \forall \epsilon>0 \text{ there exists } \delta>0 \text{ such that } \lambda (A)<\epsilon \text{ if } \nu(A)<\delta,$$
for each $A\in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$.

Now, I've already done the implication 1.$\implies$ 2. using the characterisation of absolutely continuous measure, but I don't know how to prove the reverse one.

---

Edit with attempt of solution 2.$\implies$ 1.

Since $\nu$ is Radon, for each $A\in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$, such that $\nu(A)<\sigma$ there exists an open set $U\supseteq A$ such that $\nu(U)<\sigma$. So there exist a family of disjoint open intervals $(a_1,b_1)\dots (a_m,b_m)$ such that $U=\cup_i(a_i,b_i)$, and then $\nu(U)=\sum \nu(a_i,b_i)<\sigma.$

Then, fixed $\epsilon>0, A\in \mathcal B(\Bbb R)$, there exists by hypothesis $\delta>0$ such that $\sum_i \lambda(a_i,b_i)<\epsilon$ if $\sum_i \nu(a_i,b_i)<\delta$, that is there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\lambda(U)<\epsilon$ if $\nu(U)<\delta$. And so we have that for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $$\lambda(A)<\epsilon \text{ if } \nu(A)<\delta.$$

Is it correct?

Comment: When you're covering $A$ with $U$, how do you know that $U$ is a finite union and not a countably infinite union?

Comment: @danielson: This is one of my problem! (Sorry for the delay in answering)

Comment: This is sort of a guess, but I would think what you said is valid since $\lambda(\mathbb R) < \infty$. This means that $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda((a_i,b_i)) = N < \infty$. Then you can say that there exists an $M \in \mathbb N$ such that $N - \sum_{i=1}^M \lambda((a_i,b_i))  < \varepsilon/2$. Thus, if you can get $\sum_{i=1}^M \lambda((a_i,b_i))< \varepsilon/2$ by using the characterization, you can say that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \lambda((a_i,b_i)) < \varepsilon$, and thus $\lambda(A) < \varepsilon$ by monotonicity.